# TV show with sci-fi inventions of the family member and trouble it causes

Tags: story-identification, tv, disney

SCENE-1: (face disappears)
A girl applies a cream for a pimple problem and the pimples will disappear and she is warned to not apply excess cream. In college she applies more cream and her body facial parts will disappear.

SCENE-2: (Dream world)
Same girl falls from sky with parachute and lands in classroom because of bad guy and covers with parachute cloth and she controls the dream and makes everyone in classroom be wrapped by parachute cloth to escape embarrassment.

SCENE-3: (Mermaid)
A girl becomes mermaid and swims in swimming pool.

Comment: You've tagged this with Disney does that mean you think it might be a Disney show? Can you remember when you saw this and how old it would be?

Comment: Yes Disney show/jetix I saw it in my childhood may be around 2004-2014

Comment: May be disney/jetix I saw it in my childhood may 2004-2014 I also remember  watching Aaron stone,spd power Rangers, zeke and luther that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Honey, I Shrunk the Kids: the TV Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey,_I_Shrunk_the_Kids:_The_TV_Show)* ([list of episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Honey,_I_Shrunk_the_Kids:_The_TV_Show_episodes))

[image: Promotional poster for the show]

From Episode 24, "Honey, She's Like a Fish Out of Water":

> Wayne creates a skin lotion to make people become great swimmers like fish in the water. Amy takes some of it to a pool party that she is invited to. When Amy uses the lotion, she becomes the life of the pool party so the girl who the party is being held for tries it as well. However, things go terribly wrong (as usual) when the girls find the lotion has turned them into "mermaids". They'll end up completely turning into fish unless Wayne can create an antidote. However, things get even worse when the desperate and greedy owner of the pool kidnaps the girls to use them as a money-making attraction.

From Episode 27, "Honey, I'm Rooting for the Hometeam":

> Nick is upset because he is having trouble playing baseball so he asks his dad to make some inventions to help him play baseball better. Elsewhere, Diane is worried her recital and Amy uses a cream that camouflage pimples but she uses too much and it hides her nose.

There were a few different episodes with dreams being made real, but based on the Wikipedia list of episodes and [this page](http://platypuscomix.com/hollywood/shrunktv.html), it's probably episode 19, "Honey, I'm Dreaming... But Am I?".

[image: Image of Amy in her parachute] [image: Everyone else in parachutes]

> "SECOND QUESTION IS VERBIAGE. AMY DISCARDED HER PARACHUTE AND STOOD UP BEFORE HER CLASSMATES, ONLY TO FIND HERSELF STARK NAKED. THE EXPERIENCE WAS A) SUBSERVIENT, B) MORTIFYING, OR C) IRONIC."
>   "C, ironic....because everyone's wearing parachutes now! It's the latest trend!"
>   Sure enough, they are, because Amy said so. Where Wayne failed is that he approached the problem with Morpheus logically. Since dreams are illogical, and Amy excels in randomness, she can control the dreamworld and beat Morpheus at his own game.

Found with a search for `tv show invention pimple cream mermaid` which got me the episode list, then `"honey I shrunk the kids" show dream parachute` for the dream episode.

Comment: Thanks brother I was searching it forever. Can you suggest me few top tvshows

Comment: No worries. :) At first, I was looking at the entries for the *Maniac Mansion* series, a similar "inventions make things crazy, tenuously linked to another property".